# What does the writer mean in this following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Eric Hoffer, American author and recipient of the Presidential Medal of Freedom, wrote:

> In a time of change, learners inherit the earth, while the learned find themselves beautifully equipped to deal with a world that no longer exists

What does he mean in this sentence?

Comment: What *specifically* causes you problems with this text? As it stands, I think this question is too "vague".

Answer (score 1):

[LINK](http://www.getmotivation.com/motivationblog/2009/05/continually-prepare-yourself-to-adapt-lifes-changes-by-bob-proctor/)

He means you have to keep learning or you are not still educated.

Having a degree is the step that gets you to today's information. It cannot teach you about new information discovered tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

He means that those who keep learning will be OK. Whereas those who are learned, that is, those with a prolonged formal education to the point of know some body of knowledge in depth, do not know what is going on today, at the moment.

Learners=actively learning about the world and things today.
The learned=those who have Phd's etc. but are not actively involved in learning new things.